# Where is the contradiction? $I=\int_0^\infty \frac{a^x}{x^2+1}dx,~~0<a<1$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I am considering the integral
$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{a^x}{x^2+1}dx,\quad 0<a<1$$
which showed up in attempting to solve a different question on MSE. My attempt was by considering a keyhole contour

[image]

This function has simple poles at $z=i$ and $z=-i$. We drop the integral over the big circle; the lines $A$ and $B$ each contribute the value $I$, so
$$2I=2\pi i \sum Res$$
which then leads to the solution
$$2I=2\pi i (\frac{a^i}{2i} +\frac{a^{-i}}{-2i})$$
but the RHS is purely imaginary, when $I$ should be real. When I played with this on Mathematica, the RHS and LHS (in absolute value) are completely unrelated when I numerically compute each for various values of $a$. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: It appears I utterly failed with this integral. Does anyone have any idea of how to actually solve it? Hints are welcome. (Should I make a new post?)

Comment: Please define contour. Keep in mind that contour has to converge to $\mathbb{R}$. You seems to using the fact $z = i$ is a residue then you need to make the integral as contour from y - axis .Check if real part of complex integral or imaginary part of complex integral is the required integral. It might be imaginary part of complex integral that is the integral you need. Please add ur work out, if you need more help.

Comment: @Balajisb I have edited my question. I don't know what you mean about making the contour from the y axis. My result is purely imaginary, which is problem A; problem B is that it doesn't even agree (in absolute value) to the true value (computed numerically).

Comment: While the two answers below are technically correct, the bigger issue is how you initially came up with the contour. Since $a^z = \exp\left(\log\left(a^z\right)\right)$, setting $a^z = 0$ yields no solutions for $z$. Even if there was a branch cut, you would need to define what interval of the log's argument resides in. Since the answerers have explained why your contour fails, summing those residues leads to a wrong answer. If you still insist on using Cauchy's Residue Theorem, you could draw a contour shaped like one-fourth of a pie in the first quadrant with a circular indent at $z=i$.

Comment: But it's a lot easier to just factor the denominator, do some partial fractions, and use the definition of the Exponential Integral $\operatorname{Ei}$, or maybe the sine integral $\operatorname{Si}$ and the cosine integral $\operatorname{Ci}$. The final answer should be $\frac{\pi}{2}\cos(\sin{a}) + \operatorname{Si}(\ln{a})\cos(\ln{a}) - \operatorname{Ci}(-\ln{a})\sin(\ln{a})$ after some numerical calculations.

Comment: @Accelerator What you wrote done is what Mathematica gave me; the Issue is that this "solution" now need to be integrated w.r.t. $a$, so I was looking for a "better" solution.

Comment: @Accelerator And for the contour you suggested, I should then take the real part? I  didn't understand your point about $a^z\neq 0$; how does this influence my choice of a contour?

Comment: Yes, taking the real part would work, but that contour I made up is practically a roundabout way of solving the integral because you would end up doing some partial fractions and end up using one of those nonelementary expressions anyways.

Comment: I was setting the inside of the logarithm equal to $0$ and tried to solve for $z$, and that's only to locate any branch points. If there were, for whatever reason, branch points, then a good strategy is orienting them such that you can have integrals over line segments near the branch cut that could work in your favor. But since there are no branch points (hence no branch cuts), then I guess it'd be easier to construct a contour since you wouldn't have branch cuts getting in the way. Also, I'm not sure if there's a closed form for $\int_0^1 \cos(\sin{a})da$.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

(1) If you define the integral on path $A$ is $I$, then the integral on path $B$ is $-I$ and they cancel out. You won't get $2I$ on the LHS.

(2) The integral on the large circle does NOT vanish. Think when you take $z$ with a very negative real part, for example, around $z=-R$, you get

$$a^z=\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^R,~~~~~\frac{1}{a}>1$$

hence your integral diverges on the large circle when the radius $R\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

In your contour,

I think what you are missing is the integral of the form
$$\lim_{w \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\{w e^{i \theta}: -\pi \leq \theta \leq \pi\}} \frac{e^{\log(a)z}}{z^2+1} dx$$

It is not $0$ as it involves both positive and negative $x$-axis. In fact I think it diverges.